# Installing pear on windows, wrong paths

Tags: php, pear

I'm trying to install PEAR on Windows 7.

I have php 5.4 in `d:\web\soft\php` directory, and I want to install PEAR in this directory too. I run:

```
php go-pear.phar
```

I see this:
[image]

This paths are ok for me.

Then I run enter and install it. In the end I see this warning:

> WARNING! Old version found at D:\web\soft\php, please remove it or be sure to use the new d:\web\soft\php\pear.bat command
>   
> The 'pear' command is now at your service at d:\web\soft\php\pear.bat`

and when I press `pear config-show` I see completely wrong paths related to disk `C:\`:
[image]

```
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    <not set>
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          D:\web\soft\php
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          C:\php\pear\docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          d:/web/soft/php/ext
PEAR directory                 php_dir          D:\web\soft\php\pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        C:\Users\zzz\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          C:\php\pear\cfg
PEAR data directory            data_dir         C:\php\pear\data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     C:\Users\zzz\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\download
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          D:\web\soft\php\php.exe
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         C:\Users\zzz\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         C:\php\pear\tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          C:\php\pear\www
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          c:\gnupg\gpg.exe
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       C:\Windows\pearkeys
User Configuration File        Filename         C:\Windows\pear.ini
System Configuration File      Filename         C:\Windows\pearsys.ini
```

So it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might actually want to cut&paste the *text* from the output, instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Set `PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR` to the directory where your `pear.ini` is located.

```
SETX PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR d:\web\soft\php /M
```

Answer (score -2):

Try taking a look in parameter `include_path` at your `php.ini`:

```
include_path = ".;d:\web\soft\php;d:\web\soft\php\PEAR"
```

Comment: It is set correctly. Without the `include_path` PEAR wouldn't even work.

Answer (score -2):

this is the best link i have come across so far to install pear for php
http://crc-stc.com/How_to_Install_PHP_PEAR_on_WampServer

Comment: Great that you found an answer to this question! But while the link alone may be useful, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for reference.

Comment: The link doesn't work any more, and neither did you take time to copy/paste the answer as suggested by @A.Donda: -1