# pear config-show directories

Tags: windows, wamp, pear, config

I installed pear on wamp2.1 (Apache2.2.17, PHP5.3.5 MSVC6x32) on win7x64
all in order to install PHPUnit, and everything went well, but when I execute

```
pear config-show
```

I get an unexpected output

The special directories are different from those that I set during installation, is this normal?

```
C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR>pear config-show
CONFIGURATION (CHANNEL PEAR.PHP.NET):
=====================================
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          C:\php\pear\docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          c:/wamp21/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/
PEAR directory                 php_dir          C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\pear
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          C:\php\pear\cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         C:\php\pear\data
.....
```

This is an extract from the cli installation of pear:

```
C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR>php -d phar.require_hash=0 go-pear.phar

 1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR
 2. Temporary directory for processing            : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\tmp
 3. Temporary directory for downloads             : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\tmp
 4. Binaries directory                            : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR
 5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\pear
 6. Documentation directory                       : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\docs
 7. Data directory                                : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\data
 8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\cfg
 9. Public Web Files directory                    : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\www
10. Tests directory                               : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\tests
11. Name of configuration file                    : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\pear.ini
12. Path to CLI php.exe                           : C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5
....
```

I would install pear in C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR but now I have two directory data, docs, tests

C:\php\pear\data

C:\php\pear\docs

C:\php\pear\tests

C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\data

C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\docs

C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\tests

with their subdir

a related question [Installing pear on windows, wrong paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251222/installing-pear-on-windows-wrong-paths?rq=1)[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251222/installing-pear-on-windows-wrong-paths?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your PEAR configuration file that stored the installation settings is not used. You can fix that by manually specifying it with the `-c` option:

```
$ pear -c /path/to/config/file config-show
```

Or just move it to the location that is currently shown in `pear config-show`.

Comment: You are correct. Using the `-c` option will force PEAR to use the correct `pear.ini` file. But setting the `pear.ini` in the currently shown directory is not an option. A workaround is to use `config-set` and manualy set all the variables, but it should be better if the filepath could be changed to somehow point to the right `pear.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR` to the directory where your `pear.ini` is located.

```
SETX PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR C:\wamp21\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR /M
```